# Plot states of a country with colour based on number range which includes negative values and NAs (R)

Tags: r, colors, mapping

I am trying to colour the states of a country according to numbers which contain negative numbers and NAs.
I have put my sample code below. the "data" basically has all the coordinates and polygon values.

```
Waste.Balance<-c(NA,11654.9,-6265.6,-7849.5,-9355.1,NA,6341.6,NA,
NA,-4930.6,-144.6,-1378.7,8506.7,2218.8,-7944.6,-7065.0,
-194.1,13027.0,NA,-137.3,14960.0,-8.4,-495.2,-531.4,
-525.9,NA,-10554.9,-35.2,11919.1,24824.9,-895.7,19319.0,
-72.2,-1839.9,-47247.7,-27.2,7524.1)

 ggplot(data = data) +
      geom_sf(colour="#999999", aes(fill='Waste.Balance'))+
      scale_fill_gradient(low="#ffffff", high = "#ff2015")+
      xlab("")+ylab("")+
      theme_bw()+
      theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
            axis.text = element_blank(),
            axis.ticks = element_blank(),
            panel.border = element_blank(),
            legend.position = "bottom")
```

I get this Error:

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Why is the function unable to convert the values into a continuous range of colours? This error comes even if I removed all the NAs.

Comment: Try `fill=Waste.Balance` without quotes.

Comment: Oh my God, it worked!
Thank you so much. If I was flexible enough, I'd kick myself! Hahah